# how to compact DatePicker in android

Tags: android, datepicker

I want to add `DatePicker` in my activity, but I am suffering from lack of space on screen as I want to add many other things, I have added `DatePicker` and its consuming lot of screen space hence I want compact `DatePicker` My current DatePicker looks like :

[image: Big date picker]

And I want something like :

[image: Small Date Picker]

I have tried many things but its not working as expected like changing `scaleX` and `scaleY` reducing size of `DatePicker` but its leaving blank space all around.

My layout xml contain :

```
 <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="Date" />

            <DatePicker
                android:id="@+id/dp_date_selector"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@color/lighter_gray"
                android:calendarViewShown="false"
                android:spinnersShown="true" />
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can use dialog date picker as well in that case.

Comment: no actually I want it to show current date and if user want he can change right there by scrolling.. Obviously Last option will be dialog date picker, but I want to know is this possible or not? and if not why?

Comment: @DCoder i h've tried this a lot but finally eded with dialog datePicker